How to wire a JST XSR connector
I plan to use a 2-position JST XSR connector for the power supply. The datasheet states that the compatible wire is AWG #36, but it lacks information on crimping terminals. I have a connector socket (02XSR-36S), but simply press-fitting a stripped #36 wire into the contact doesn't create a reliable connection. What is the proper way to make a power connection with the XSR? Should I solder or crimp the wires by hand?

The XSR is an IDC (Insulation Displacement Connector). You ask about crimping terminals, but here are no crimp terminals in that connector.
If you don't know about IDT (Insulation Displacement Technology), you can learn about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDC_(electrical_connector)
Watch some YouTube videos: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Insulation+Displacement
TL;DR: you press an unstripped wire into the plastic barbs and then into the blades of the contact (ideally with the appropriate tool), until the blades cut through the insulation and connect to the core inside the wire.

There is a rather ominous "applicable to automatic ID machines" blurb on the datasheet and a lack of a 0.6mm line on their application tooling selector chart (https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/2584/ID%20Tools.pdf). You could try your luck with a very fine screwdriver but a prewired jumper is probably the best way to get a known good connection.

In practice there's just no way to use these connectors meaningfully without buying the tool from JST. (I mean, I can't even reliably work with 2mm IDC connectors without the tool, imagine 0.6mm.) There are some JST approved subcontractors who supposedly can make cable assemblies out of every JST connector out there, but unless one has big production volumes that's probably expensive.

Thanks for your helpful comments. I attempted to use a cutter knife and a clothespin to insert one end of the 36 wire into the contact from the top, then pulled the rest of the wire down so that the blade cut it in the middle. With some focus, I was able to make the connection, but the ordinary cutter blade was too blunt for the <0.3mm opening. I’ve ordered a set of 0.1/0.2mm scribe tool and will provide an update later.
